# Retrieving exact node id in neo4j cypher

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j-jdbc 2.3.2 as my neo4j client for java. When I executed following cypher query 
`match(p:Person) where p.id_number='761201948V' return p.id;`
 it will return P2547228 as node id. I feel like id is same as other properties of the node as I can use it inside where clauses. 
 
 But here I'm expecting an integer which can use inside this query `START p=node('node.id') return p;` Is this id is an internal thing to neo4j db? and is there a way to retrieve this id?
From the following two cyphers what is most efficient one?(if both referring same node)

1. `START p=node('2547223') return p;`
2. `match(p:Person) where p.id='P2547228' return p;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `ID(x)` function for this. Note, that `ID(x)` and `x.id` are a complete different thing. The former returns the internal node/relationship id managed by Neo4j itself. The latter gives the `id` property which is managed by the user and not by the database itself.

Also note, that a node/relationship ID is always numeric.

Using `START` is pretty much old school and shouldn't be used any more (except for accessing manual indexes):

```
start p=node(2547228) return p
```

This one is a equivalent statement. It is highly efficient since it just needs to do a simple seek operation on the node store:

```
match(p:Person) where id(p)=2547228 return p;
```

Looking for a property requires either a node label scan or a schema index lookup:

```
match(p:Person) where p.id=2547228 return p;
```

Just check out the query plans on your own by prefixing the statement with `PROFILE`.